# Why is my code not adding data to my json file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, jsx

I'm making a sign-up page, and can't seem to come across why it's not working.

Edit: updated the code to remove the userObject. Still am not able to get the code to actually post the data to my json file.

New code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Signup = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  console.log(formData)

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(formData); 

    fetch("http://localhost:8000/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    }).then(() => {
      window.location.href = "/profile"; 
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Confirm Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="confirmPassword"
            value={formData.confirmPassword}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Old code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Signup = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  console.log(formData)

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userObject = {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password,
    };
 
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userObject),
    }).then(() => {
      window.location.href = "/profile"; 
    });
  };

  console.log(userObject)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Confirm Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="confirmPassword"
            value={formData.confirmPassword}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

When I console.log the formData, it is receiving the data, but when I try and console.log the userObject, it comes back as not defined. I've been Googling for hours, checked solutions to similar problems on here, and trying different methods, but can't seem to get it to save to my json file. Hoping that with some new eyes I could get some help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you opening up the console and manually typing `console.log(userObject)`?

Comment: `userObject` only exists in the scope of the `handleSubmit` function. You are trying to log it in a place where it does not exist.

Comment: And your dev console should be yelling at you about this. You should be getting an error along the lines of `Uncaught ReferenceError: userObject is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. I'm sorry to tell you, but your `console.log` function is not called at the right time!

Your code should be:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const Signup = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  console.log(formData)

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userObject = {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password,
    };

    console.log(userObject);
 
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userObject),
    }).then(() => {
      window.location.href = "/profile"; 
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Confirm Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="confirmPassword"
            value={formData.confirmPassword}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Like spender said:

> userObject only exists in the scope of the handleSubmit function

Answer (score 0):

scope error occured.
If you want to log the userObject, you can move the console.log statement inside the handleSubmit,

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const userObject = {
    email: formData.email,
    password: formData.password,
  };

  console.log(userObject); // moved inside handleSubmit function

  fetch("http://localhost:8000/users", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userObject),
  }).then(() => {
    window.location.href = "/profile"; 
  });
};
```

Comment: Even with this change, it's not logging anything with the command, and when I directly enter console.log(userObject) in my console, it still says it's undefined.